# GraphQL with multiple objects: should I keep all objects in a single query?

Tags: graphql

I´m building a SaaS B2B application composed of several different objects. Examples:

- Users
- Customers
- StockItens
- StockLevels
- PriceList
- Sales
- Returns
- Etc...

I´ll have around 40 different objects, that can be listed and created, edited, and deleted individually.

Facing the GraphQL concepts for the first time, should I build a large schema for all objects, like the example below, or should I keep each object on its own query.

```
query {
  viewer {
    Users {
      id
      firstName 
      lastName
      address
      city
      ...
    }
    Customers {
        id
        firstName
        lastName
        address
        city
        rating
        ...

    }
    StockItens {
        id 
        item_id
        sales {
            id
            dateTime
            qty
            unitValue
            totalValue
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
    StockLevels {
        ...
    }
    PriceList {
        ...
    }
    Sales {
        id
        dateTime
        qty
        unitValue
        totalValue
        ...
    }
    Returns {
        ...
    }
  }
}
```

Looking for the first option (keeping everything into one single query) seens logical as I will be using fragments to access the desired piece of information, but then I will have a huge schema with lots of inter relations.

PLease advice what would be the best practice on that use case.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do not write a query where you add all needed data but use the concept of fragments as you already pointed out.

And you fetch only the data which are needed for the current page. So the throughput is kept minimal.

e.g.
If you have a page where you update a user you just fetch the needed data for this user in a specialized query. The query consists of fragments.
The fragments are related to the subcomponents which are used in the page, for example a form where you show the data of the user.
The fragment of the form defines the data it needs from the user and the update page combines the fragments to the query.

```js
// in user form component
const userFormFragments = {
  name: "UserForm",
  document: `fragment UserForm on User {
    id
    name
  }`
};

// in update user page
const userQuery = `query getUserQuery($userId: ID!) {
  getUser(userId: $userId) {
    ...${userFormFragment.name}
  }
  ${userFormFragment.document}
}`
```